# access twig variable array of objects

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have a twig variable and its contain :

```
object(Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Relacionado)[366]
  protected 'video' => 
    object(Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Video)[339]
      private 'id' => int 1
  **protected 'categoria' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria)[397]
      public '__initializer__' => 
        object(Closure)[388]
      public '__cloner__' => 
        object(Closure)[389]
      public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
      private 'id' (Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria) => int 1**
```

I want to access the category id Variable in TWIG

My twig file:

```
<div class="Descripcion">
    <h1> {{ video.name }} ( {{ video.duracion}} min ) </h1>

                        {% for tag in tags %}

                             {{ dump(tag) }}

                        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

and mycontroller render:

```
$tagvideo = $em->getRepository('VideoBundle:Relacionado')->findCategoriaVideo($video->getId());

return $this->render('VideoBundle:Default:video.html.twig', array('video' => $video, 'relacionados' => $relacionados, 'categorias' => $categorias ,'tags' => $tagvideo));
```

and my query dql

```
public function findCategoriaVideo($idvideo)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $dql = 'SELECT c,r FROM VideoBundle:Relacionado r INNER JOIN r.video c WHERE r.video  = :id';
        $consulta = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $consulta->setParameter('id',$idvideo);
        return $consulta->getResult();

    }
```

I think that i am using wrong my assosiation entyties:

```
/**
 * Relacionado
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Video\VideoBundle\Entity\RelacionadoRepository")
 */

class Relacionado
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Video")
    */
    protected $video;
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne (targetEntity = "Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria")
    */
    protected $categoria;


class Categoria
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany (targetEntity = "Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Relacionado", mappedBy = "Categoria")
 */
    private $id;

class Video
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")

     */
    private $id;
```

In table Relacionado I relate the videos to the category associated with each video,

but i dont know because the result Video is correct but Category no! :(

I cant access entity Categoria because its not mapped correctly:

```
protected 'categoria' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria)[397]
```

Comment: What object do you dumped?

Comment: It would help if you posted the controller that returns the object to the twig file and the twig file

Comment: Victor i dumped the variable tab its variable that i render

Comment: splendonia i have posted the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem!
The Problem was the consult:

```
public function findCategoriaVideo($idvideo)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $dql = 'SELECT r,c FROM VideoBundle:Relacionado r JOIN r.categoria c WHERE r.video  = :id';
        $consulta = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $consulta->setParameter('id',$idvideo);
        //$consulta->setMaxResults(8);
       return $consulta->getResult();

    }
```

and my class:

```
class Relacionado
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoria_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $categoria;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne (targetEntity = "Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Video")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="video_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   **/
    protected $video;


class Categoria
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Relacionado")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="categoria_id")
     *
     */
```

whit that asossiantions Entitys i can acces my Categoria object.

Thanks a lot for all

Answer (score 0):

If your twig variable's name is entity, then you can access the category by using :

```
 {{ entity.getCategory }}
```

Comment: Couldn't you also just use {{ entity.categoria.id }} ?

Comment: {{ entity.getCategory }} and {{ entity.category }} mean the same thing in twig if you are using standard entity templates. joe42 is correct presuming you have the stock getId function.

Answer (score 0):

Not found:

```
{{ dump(tag.getCategoria) }}

or

tag.categoria.id
```

any found!!!

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined property: Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Relacionado::$Categoria in C:\wamp\www\video\src\Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Relacionado.php line 45
```

but i have define this property in my Entity Relacionado

```
class Relacionado
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Video")
    */
    protected $video;
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria")
    */
    protected $categoria;
```

I think that the problem can be in:

```
*protected 'categoria' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\Video\VideoBundle\Entity\Categoria)[397]
```

Why use Proxies__CG__ ¿?¿?¿?

Comment: Creo que estoy usando mis malas asociaciones de entidades: